# Why use "\t" instead of "<press TAB>" for strings?

Tags: c++, tabs, conventions

I just tried compiling some C++ code that used the literal Tab character (as in I pressed the `TAB` key on my keyboard) inside a string. And, to my surprise, it compiled fine. In retrospect I guess that makes sense, since it's a character just like any other.

```
cout << "Tab: [TAB]";
```

Before now I've always used `\t` to define tabs in strings.

```
cout << "Tab: [\t]";
```

Obviously code using literal `TAB`s in strings would suffer greatly in readability, but is there a technical reason to use `\t` other than convention?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you have code that demonstrates the functionality you're trying to achieve or highlights an issue you were having?

Comment: @Xirema I'm not sure how to be more clear about it...why should I use `"\t"` in a C++ string rather than literally pressing the `TAB` key on my keyboard. The functionality appears to be the same either way. So why is one better than the other?

Comment: @Xirema It's clear enough.

Comment: Many developers have editor settings which automatically convert tabs into spaces. If you used literal tabs, they would get converted into spaces which is probably undesirable.

Comment: For one thing, you can tell the difference between \t and a bunch of spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but is there a technical reason to use `\t` other than convention?

Sure there are technical reasonings. Using

```
cout << "Tab: [\t]";
```

would work independently of the target systems actual character encoding.

The source file could use a different encoding as the target system does, e.g. UTF8 for source, but [EBCDIC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimals_Interchange_Code) at the target system.
`'\t'` will always be translated to the correct character code though, thus the code is portable.

---

Also as mentioned in [merlin2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391161/merlin2011)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564994/why-use-t-instead-of-press-tab-for-strings#comment58818373_35564994) many IDE's will just replace `TAB` with a specific number of spaces.

Comment: Would that be determined at compilation time (character encoding of the compiler's computer) or at run time (character encoding of the running terminal)?

Comment: @TheSchwa It's resolved at compile time, consider some cross compiler.

Comment: I don't get the downvote actually? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: So is the character encoding possible but unlikely to occur? I notice that both ASCII and UTF8 use the same encoding for Tab (assuming I read the tables correctly).